# Specify Size of SURF Points Extracted

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, surf

I am trying to extract the SURF points in order to do pattern matching between an input image and a training set of images. I have modified the MATLAB's HOG detection code. However, I am getting an error because the SURF Features for the different images are of different sizes. This was addressed in the HOG detector by CellSize but there is no such parameter for SURF Points.

Is there a way to ensure that the SURF Features from all images are of the same size ?

The error : 
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Error in SURF2 
        features(i, :) = extractFeatures(img,points);

```
%1.  Load Image Sets 
imgSets = [ imageSet(fullfile('Patterns', 'Cat1')), ...
            imageSet(fullfile('Patterns', 'Cat2')), ...
            imageSet(fullfile('Patterns', 'Cat3'))...
            imageSet(fullfile('Patterns', 'Cat4'))];
{imgSets.Description } % display all labels on one line
[imgSets.Count]         % show the corresponding count of images

%2.  Prepare Training and Validation Image Sets
%2.1 Balance number of each training set 
% determine the smallest amount of images in a category
minSetCount = min([imgSets.Count]);
% Use partition method to trim the set.
imgSets = partition(imgSets, minSetCount, 'randomize');
% Notice that each set now has exactly the same number of images.
[imgSets.Count]

%2.2  Separate sets into training and validation data. 30% of the images
%for training data and the remainder 70% for validation data
[trainingSets, validationSets] = partition(imgSets, 0.3, 'randomize');


img = read(trainingSets(3), 4);
img = rgb2gray(img);
%3.   Detect SURF Points
points =detectSURFFeatures(img);
points = points.selectStrongest(15);
[feats,vPoints] = extractFeatures(img,points);
SURFFeatureSize = length(feats);


trainingFeatures = [];
trainingLabels   = [];

for digit = 1:numel(trainingSets)

    numImages1 = trainingSets(digit).Count;           
    features = zeros(numImages1,SURFFeatureSize,'single');

    for i = 1:numImages1

        img = read(trainingSets(digit), i);
        img = rgb2gray(img);
        points = detectSURFFeatures(img);
        features(i, :) = extractFeatures(img,points);
    end

    if digit== 1 %plaid = 5
    label = [trainingSets(digit).Description,blanks(6)];
    end

    if digit== 2 %patternless = 11
    label = [trainingSets(digit).Description];
    end

    if digit== 3 %striped = 7
    label = [trainingSets(digit).Description,blanks(4)];
    end

    if digit== 4 %irregular = 9
    label = [trainingSets(digit).Description,blanks(2)];
    end

    % Use the imageSet Description as the training labels. .
    labels = repmat(label, numImages1, 1);

    trainingFeatures = [trainingFeatures; features];   %#ok<AGROW>
    trainingLabels   = [trainingLabels;   labels  ];   %#ok<AGROW>

end
```

Thank you.

Comment: There's no way you can enforce a minimum or maximum number of SURF points per image.  You have two options: (1) Use a cell array and place each set of features in a cell. (2) If the total number of features detected is less than what you expect, then fill the column with up to as many features that were detected, then fill the rest of what is missing with something... like zeroes.

Comment: @rayryeng I'm implementing the second option now. I'm not sure how the first option (using a cell array) would work out, but the second should be find. Thank you.

Comment: Would you like me to write an answer or have you figured that out already?

Comment: @rayryeng I commented with my implementation. Feel free to post another if you think others would benefit from it.

I am learning about using cell arrays to implement it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SURF directly the same way you use HOG. `extractHOGFeatures` computes a single histogram describing the entire image, while `extractSURFFeatures` takes a set of points, and computes a descriptor around each point, so it returns multiple vectors. `extractHOGFeatures` can also compute point descriptors, but `extractSURFFeatures` cannot compute a global image descriptor.

If you want to use SURF for image classficiation, such as digit recognition, You would need to convert a set of SURF descriptors into a single vector. One way to do this is to use the [bag-of-features approach](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html).

Comment: That makes much sense! thanks. But, if i would like to extract BRISK or FAST features which give a matrix of descriptors, how can I convert this to a bag of words? The bag of features function does this automatically for SURF alone

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments provided by @rayryeng, I have padded the array of detected features to a set expected array size as done below :

```
img = read(trainingSets(3), 4);
img = rgb2gray(img);
%3.   Detect SURF Points
points =detectSURFFeatures(img);
points = points.selectStrongest(15);
[feats,vPoints] = extractFeatures(img,points);
currentSize = size(feats);
rowSize = currentSize (:,1);
expectedRowSize = 15;
differenceRowSize = abs(expectedRowSize- rowSize);

if rowSize ~= expectedRowSize
    z =zeros(differenceRowSize,64,'single');
    feats= vertcat(feats,z);
end
```

There are other ways to pad arrays (e.g. use of padarray) but I was more familiar with this method.

Please feel free to provide any alternative methods to benefit others.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not going to work. Yes, this will make the feature sets the same size, but this padding does not have any semantic meaning. It will not help you classify images.

Comment: @Dima Thanks! can you please elaborate on how I can go about implementing a bag of features approach for a descriptor such as BRISK, FAST etc , since the bag of features function does this using SURF

Comment: @Dima, I have attempted to create a feature vector representative of this matrix. I am new to stackoverflow, should i create a new question about it or edit this question? Thank you.